# Making incremental update to a partitioned hive table fast

Tags: hadoop, hive, etl, partition

I have two hive tables T1 and T2. T1 is an external table partitioned by column date1,hour1. It also has another date column called date2 (different from date1).

T2 is a hive table partitioned by date2.

I will get data incrementally every hour, and I can easily add it to table T1 with dynamic partition.

I want an efficient way to select data from T1 and load data incrementally into T2, partitioned by date2.

This is what I am doing now

```
insert into T2

select
    *,
    date2
from

    (
      select * from T1 where date1="a constant date" and hour1 = "a constant hour"
    ) T1SubQuery
left outer join
    T2
on
    T1SubQuery.idColumn = T2.idColumn
where
    T2.idColumn is null
```

I am doing a left outer join and "where T1.idColumn is null" to simulate "where not in". And I am doing that to avoid duplicate data, the query can run multiple times and I want it to be idempotent.

**Questions**

1. Which partitions from T2 will be used in this query? How can I minimize the number of partitions used?
2. What is the most efficient way to do this kind of idempotent incremental data load?

Answer (score 0):

1. All partitions should be affected on T2 since your where condition does not filter them out
2. A more typical way to do this is to create new partitions in T2 corresponding to the new partitions in T1 and insert the data from t1 into t2 on those partitions.   The strategy you are using is not built for speed but instead for the specialized purpose of finding the missing data from T1 and inserting them . That is maybe not the most optimal way  to do larger volume / bulk inserts.